# Top fix for bootstrap divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.divCounterText{
    text-align: center;
}

.resultsCounterTxt{
 color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12pt;
 padding:1%;
 text-align:center;
}

.resultsCtrValue {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.touchImageSearch {
    width: 83%;
    height: 70%;
    outline: none;
    cursor: hand;
    padding:1%;
 text-align:center;
}

.orDivText{
 padding:20%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#orText{
 height: 100%;
}

#searchManual{
 border-radius: 5pt;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: center;
}

.paddingCol{
 padding:1%;
}
```

I have following code and it changes height to 27px instead of default height of `col-md-1`. What should be the fix for it?

Code:

```
 <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 clearfix divCounterText">
    <span class="orDivText">or</span> 
 </div>
```

span or is displayed on top with space at bottom on a navbar / div.

Adding screenshot for better understanding, with different div.

[image: screenshot with problem]

code:

```html
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" id="orText">
    <div class="orDivText">or</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 paddingCol">
    <input type="text" id="searchManual" class="form-control" placeholder="Last,First,Res #, Visual ID"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
    <div id="arrivalDate" class="calanderSize" 
                    ng-click="searchReservationVm.arrivalDtOpen($event)">
      <span>
       <button tabindex="4" class="dateSearchBar" class="btn btn-primary" id="one"
                                datepicker-popup="{{'MMM d'}}"
                                ng-model="searchReservationVm.searchRQ.arrivalDate"
                                is-open="searchReservationVm.arrivalDtOpened"
                                ng-change="searchReservationVm.arrivalDateChange()"
                                datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                show-weeks="false"
                                current-text="Reset To Today's Date"
                                ng-focus="searchReservationVm.arrivalDtOpen($event)">
        <div class="text calFontDate" title="Select Arrival Date">
         {{ searchReservationVm.searchRQ.arrivalDate | date : 'MMM' }}</br>
         <div class="datediv">
         {{  searchReservationVm.searchRQ.arrivalDate | date : 'd' }}
         </div>
        </div>
       </button>
      </span>
                </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Did you forget to add in the code?

Comment: "_instead of default height of 'col-md-1'_" You realize col is for column and has to do with width, not height right?